# different layouts on different views cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this on my controller:

```
class EmployeeAccountsController extends AppController
{
var $layout = 'login';

public function login()
{

}
public function main_board()
{

}

}
```

what I want to do is that to assign different layouts when I call the view for login() and the view for the main_board.

login() must have layout:login.ctp
main_board() must have layout:main_board()

is it possible for a single controller to have different layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is, and callback beforeFilter into your controller like:

```
class EmployeeAccountsController extends AppController {

  protected $layout = 'login';

  public function beforeFilter() {
      parent::beforeFilter(); //call parent before filter

      $this->layout = $this->layout;
  }
}
```

In this case EmployeeAccounts controller will have login layout for all views.

EDIT: just define layout especially for action

```
public function action() {   
 $this->layout = 'layout1';
}

public function action2() {   
 $this->layout = 'layout2';
}
```

Comment: amm what I want is to have login layout for login view and main_board layout for main_board view. In short, is it possible to have multiple layouts on a single controller and these layouts will be assigned to different views also on the same controller.

Comment: YeaH! That's what I'm talking about, Thank you very much! people here are always saving my day.